# Unable to import python module in script, but can in command prompt

Tags: python, import, module, scipy

I have install scipy to read data from a .mat file. When I am in Python in the command prompt I am able to type the following and get the value I desire:

**Command Prompt**

```
>>> import scipy
>>> import scipy.io
>>> from scipy.io import loadmat
>>> x=loadmat('C:\My websites\Rooftop PV.mat')
>>> size = x['component']['Size'][0][0][0][0]
>>> print(size)
150
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\...\\Documents\\anaconda3\\python.exe'
```

However, when I run the .py script...

**.py script**

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
import scipy
import scipy.io
from scipy.io import loadmat

x = loadmat('C:\My websites\Rooftop PV.mat')
size = x['component']['Size'][0][0][0][0]
print(size)
```

it is unable to find the scipy.io module, producing this error:

**Error:**

```
 C:\Python\pythonw.exe
 File "C:\Python\testmatfile.py", line 4, in <module>
     import scipy.io
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.io'
```

Any ideas on why this might be? Thanks!

Comment: Can you import sys and share sys.executable for both of these examples?

Comment: I updated the outputs for each example with sys.executable results.

Comment: I think you might be using different python environments between your interpreter and script examples.  It looks like one is anaconda and the other might be a different installation.  Can you share how you are running the script?

Comment: I am running the script from IDLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see there are two different python executables used. `C:\\...\\Documents\\anaconda3\\python.exe` is used in the first case and `C:\Python\pythonw.exe` is used in the second case. You have your lib installed for the first python executable (into the corresponding path), so you just need to run

```
C:\Python\pythonw.exe -m pip install <lib_name>
```

command to install the lib into the path related to the second executable. You can also use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or [docker](https://www.docker.com/) to run your script into isolated env with all required dependencies.